# mypy (typeshed) rejects csv.excel as a possible value for the return of csv.Sniffer.sniff

Tags: python-3.x, csv, mypy, typeshed

Using mypy to statically check some of my code and got this problem. Code example:

```
import csv

d: csv.Dialect = csv.excel
d = csv.Sniffer().sniff("a")
```

but mypy gives this error in the first assignment to `d`:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[excel]", variable has type "Dialect")
```

So the natural fix for this is to change the type of the variable.

```
from typing import Type

import csv

d: Type[csv.Dialect] = csv.excel
d = csv.Sniffer().sniff("a")
```

But now I get this error on the second assignment to d:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dialect", variable has type "Type[Dialect]")
```

But this is odd because `csv.excel` is a valid return for the `sniff` function so surely they must have the same type.

Python 3.7.3,  mypy 0.701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the `typeshed`: I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/2987)

According to `typeshed`, `Sniffer.sniff` returns a value of type `csv.Dialect` whereas in fact it returns a value of type `Type[csv.Dialect]`